# apache mod_headers Date: Header

Tags: apache, mod-headers

Folks,
  Need to convert the following request header to a different format:

```
RequestHeader set Date "%{TIME_WDAY}e"
```

The %t variable looks like :

```
t=1367272677754275
```

Would like the Date= to look like:

```
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2007 19:44:46 +0000
```

How is this done?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `%t` coming from `mod_headers`?

Comment: What is the context here ? Are you serving a web application ? If yes, can you set the Date header directly in your web application ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with the documented functionality of `mod_headers`. This module only supports the follwing variables (from the [doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#header)):

```
%t          The time the request was received in Universal Coordinated Time since the epoch (Jan. 1, 1970) measured in microseconds. The value is preceded by t=.
%D          The time from when the request was received to the time the headers are sent on the wire. This is a measure of the duration of the request. The value is preceded by D=. The value is measured in microseconds.
%{FOOBAR}e  The contents of the environment variable FOOBAR.
%{FOOBAR}s  The contents of the SSL environment variable FOOBAR, if mod_ssl is enabled.
```

Unless you continually want to set an environment variable to your current date and pull it in using `mod_env`, I suggest you use [`mod_rewrite`](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html#TIME_WDAY).

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer here is a mod_headers.c patch to add additional authentication information required by AWS and GCS